# Pandas conditional parsing of a column

Tags: python, pandas, parsing, lambda

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
    CCDS    Size    gene    exonCount
10804   NM_001320648_exon_4_0_chr21_44515804_r  50  U2AF1L5 8
9385    NM_018964_intron_9_0_chr21_43967251_f   6921    SLC37A1 21
1253    NM_004540_intron_4_0_chr21_22664562_f   32141   NCAM2   18
5233    NM_203417_intron_1_0_chr21_35893957_r   1878    RCAN1   4
3242    NM_001353691_intron_0_0_chr21_32493156_r    3684    TIAM1   30
```

I'd like to parse the CCDS column and introduce a new column called `farme` in a way that:

1) if the final field of the CCDS column (after parsing based on "_") is `f`, then the `frame` value is `df['CCDS'].str.split('_').str[3]+1`; &

2) if the final field of the CCDS column is `r`, then the `frame` value would be equal to absolute value of `|exonCount-df['CCDS'].str.split('_').str[3]|`

I have tried to devise a lambda function, but I am not sure how I can elaborate the `else` condition:

```
df['frame'] = df.Set.map( lambda x: df['CCDS'].str.split('_').str[3]+1
                         if intronExon_LDU['CCDS'].str.split('_').str[7] == 'f' 
                         else ????)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `np.where` (can generalise to multiple/nested conditions easily)

```
v = df['CCDS'].str.split('_').str[3].astype(int)
df['frame'] = np.where(df['CCDS'].str.endswith('f'), v + 1, v)
```

Or, `loc` with a boolean mask,

```
df['frame'] = v
df.loc[df['CCDS'].str.endswith('f'), 'frame'] += 1
```

The mask is generated cleanly with `str.endswith`.

Comment: How can I use multiple condition with np.where in a way that I could:


`test['frame'] = np.where(test['category']=='intron'
                         & test['CCDS'].str.endswith('r'),
                         abs(v - ((test['exonCount'].values)-1)))`

Comment: @RezaJabal take a look at numpy.select. Its usage is quite similar.

Comment: Thank you for your help!